# Cannot set text color of attributed placeholder in subclassed UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Here's a dumbed-down version of my `UITextField` subclass:

```
class MyTextField: UITextField {

    override func drawPlaceholder(in rect: CGRect) {
        if let placeholder = self.placeholder {
            print(placeholder) // -> prints the value
            let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red]
            self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder, attributes: attributes)
        }
    }
}
```

In IB, the textfield is assigned to my subclass but it doesn't matter whether I put it as "Plain" or "Attributed", the font, the color, etc. I do give it an initial placeholder value but when I run the app it's just blank. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the `drawPlaceholder` method and not calling `super`. And your replacement code makes no attempt to actually draw the placeholder text. Therefore the placeholder will never appear.

Why don't you override the setter for the `placeholder` property so it sets the `attributedPlaceholder` as needed. Then you don't need to override `drawPlaceholder` and everything will work.

Comment: Aren't I making an attempt to draw the `attributedPlaceholder` with this line? `self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder, attributes: attributes)`

Comment: Not at all. That code simply sets the property but does not do any drawing. The drawing is normally done in the `drawPlaceholder` method but you are preventing that code from running.

Comment: The call to `super` was the fix. An air-headed mistake. I'm not sure how to implement setting the `attributedPlaceholder` within an override of the `placeholder` property but thanks for the suggestion!